# Save assembly resource data to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have a c# program generating some WebPages. In my project I have added some JavaScript files to the project via the ResourceManager.

Now I want to get all the ResourceNames and save them to my Destination path.

I know this question have been asked a million times in here but I can not get it to work.

Here I try to list all my resources

```
foreach (var res in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    ....
}
```

But I do not get the Resource names in res but 
`"WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1.resources"` the first time in the loop 
and  `"WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Resources.resources"`    second time
and  `"WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Resources.Designer.cs"` third time

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just getting the names of the manifest resources, which is not the same thing as Resource file (resx) resources.

To get the resource file resources from a manifest resource file name like  `"WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Resources.resources"` you would have to do:

```
foreach (var manifestResourceName in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(manifestResourceName))
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            using (var rr = new ResourceReader(stream))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in rr)
                {
                    var name = resource.Key.ToString();

                    string resourceType;
                    byte[] dataBytes;

                    rr.GetResourceData(name, out resourceType, out dataBytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can save the bytes wherever you want.